# What is the correct way to increase nf_conntrack in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

Yesterday I had issues with my database server dropping packets with:

```
[Tue Feb 28 21:01:00 2023] nf_conntrack: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
```

I know there a plenty of solutions easy to find in google to increase the table size.

So I did `sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=4194304`

But they also say to increase the hash table, and they are all for different linux distributions or very old kernels.

```
echo "options nf_conntrack expect_hashsize=1048576 hashsize=1048576" >/etc/modprobe.conf
```

Is this the right way to do in Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15 (default) or newer I use 5.11

And how can I verify if the new hashsize is being applied? and how to apply it without a reboot?

Comment: `sudo cat /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize` ?
Also, `echo "1048576" > /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize`?

Comment: How can you be sure that just echoing that values will apply then without a reboot ?

Comment: I finally found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer... it can be done with sysctl.conf.

The parameter is `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets`